# Python error: int argument required

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-error-1064

What am I doing wrong here?

```
 i = 0
 cursor.execute("insert into core_room (order) values (%i)", (int(i))
```

Error:

```
 int argument required
```

The database field is an int(11), but I think the %i is generating the error.

**Update:**

Here's a more thorough example:

```
time = datetime.datetime.now()
floor = 0
i = 0
```

try:
     booster_cursor.execute('insert into core_room (extern_id, name, order, unit_id, created, updated) values (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)', (row[0], row[0], i, floor, time, time,))
 except Exception, e:
        print e

Error:

```
  (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order, unit_id, created, updated) values ('99', '99', '235', '12', '2009-07-24 1' at line 1")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two things. First, use `%s` and not `%i`. Second, parameters must be in a tuple - so you need `(i,)` (with comma after `i`).

Also, `ORDER` is a keyword, and should be escaped if you're using it as field name.

Comment: The %i argument is a int in the db. I need to use %s?

Comment: @slypete: Yes, use `%s`. MySQLdb uses `format` as its default `paramstyle`. PEP 249 for more info: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/

Comment: So, MySQLdb is only capable of inserting into columns that are varchar?  That cannot be!!

Comment: @slypete:  "a sql error from the MySQL server".  Please update the question with the new code and the actual error message.

Comment: `%s` doesn't mean string here, so it's not limited to `VARCHAR`. If you give it an `int`, it will expand to a numeric literal in SQL. For the reason why your query still doesn't work, see the updated answer.

Comment: @slypete:  the column's datatype has nothing to do with the `%s`.  That is just the convention for how arguments are passed to MySQLdb's `execute` method.

Comment: Thanks I had multiple problems. Main one being order used as a column name!

Answer (score 1):

I believe the second argument to execute() is expected to be an iterable.  IF this is the case you need to change:

```
(int(i))
```

to:

```
(int(i),)
```

to make it into a tuple.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using `?` instead of `%i` probably. And you're missing a parenthesis.

```
cursor.execute("insert into core_room (order) values (?)", (int(i),))
```

Comment: @Evan: you definitely have the right idea, but this `paramstyle` is known as `qmark`, and AFAIK is not supported by MySQLdb.

Comment: Ya, I just wrote it quick to demo my bad.